# I don't know what do about about a module of python that dissapered

Tags: python, matplotlib

Yes you read that right, I've been doing exercises with matplotlib from Python CrashCourse. While working on a new file inside my directory for projects it marked me an error when I tried to run the file. It told me the module matplotlib did not exist, even though I've been using it for a month. I tried to run my old files in the same directory with matplotlib but I couldn't, it told me that it didn't existed which is odd. I have spend all day installing it over and over again, I checked that I am using the right version for my pc. When I test it on the terminal I don't have any problem, it tells me that it is already installed but everytime a try to run a file in VisualStudio in the directory I work or any other it tells me that the module doesn't exist.

Here is my code

```
import csv
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt



filename = 'sitka_weather_07-2014.csv'
with open(filename) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    #We save the first line  using a csv function
    header_row = next(reader)
    
    '''#We use enumerate() to put an index on each value
    for index, column_header in enumerate(header_row):
        print(index, column_header)'''
    #We get the high temperatures    
    highs = []
    for row in reader: #We continue in the second line
        highs.append(int(row[1]))
    #print(highs)
    #Plot data
    fig = plt.figure(dpi=128, figsize=(10,6))
    plt.plot(highs, c='red')

    #Format plot
    plt.title("Daily high temperatures, July 2014", fontsize=24)
    plt.xlabel('', fontsize=16)
    plt.ylabel('Temperature (F)', fontsize=16)
    plt.tick_param(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=16)

    plt.show()
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I tested it typing

````
Python 3.7.1 (v3.7.1:260ec2c36a, Oct 20 2018, 14:05:16) [MSC v.1915 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import matplotlib
>>> ```

It shows no error. 


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9JXC.png
````

Comment: Try it in python idle, see if that works.

Comment: I am using 3.7.1 If I did how could tell or switch back?

Comment: In the picture it showed 3.7.5, look in the bottom left. If you click on it you can change the versions.

Comment: Whatever version you installed matplotlib on, that is the own you need to switch to. If you dont know you can always install it again: do pip[python version] install matplotlib
example:
pip3.8 install matplotlib

Comment: Thank you so much. :D I switched it to 3.7.1 and now it works again. Not sure when I changed it but THANKS, THANKS, THANKS!

Comment: No problem. I made a official answer so other people can see with better detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You accidentally switched python versions in visual code.
To fix this problem you have to go to the bottom right where it says the python version and click it to change it.

[image: Example]

If you want to download matplotlib in another version you would have to do:

```py
pip(python version) install matplotlib
```

Ex:

```py
pip3.7 install matplotlib
```